# About upload binary on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I have uploaded binary on itunes connect only for iphone with iphone connect , but issue is still apple review my app on ipad. my first version 1.0 not reviewed on ipad but when i uploaded new binary with new version 1.0.1 it reviewed on ipad and my app will be rejected what is the solution for that. and i also want to remove ipad screenshot tab from itunes. it is possible? give any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All applications will be reviewed on an iPad, even if they are designed only for iPhone. An iPhone app run on an iPad with a black border around it at equivalent resolution or with a X2 zoom (height / width proportion is that of an iPhone 3"5 )

You can't remove iPad screenshot tab from iTunes, but when sending an iPhone only designed app you don't need to upload iPad screenshots.

All what is required is that the application still run on iPad the same way it would on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks Jerome,
There is any solution to pass app review without any modification in app.